# UICollectionView Memory Leak (with UIWebView or UIImageView inside cells)

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my app, I have a UICollectionView with some of cells with images from web and some with Youtube videos via UIWebView. When I press Back via NavigationController memory seems to add up more and more every time. I tried disabling video player, it helped a bit, but still..

**CollectionViewController**

```
    var listOfData = [SingleData]()
    var Data:[[String:AnyObject]]?{    
            didSet{
                for asset in Data! {
                        let info = SingleData.init(Data: asset)
                        listOfData.append(info)
                 }
            }
        }


    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        listOfData.removeAll()
        Data?.removeAll()
        imageCache.removeAllObjects()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return  listOfData.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Data Single Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewControllerCell
            cell.oneData = listOfData[indexPath.item] 
            return cell
    }
```

**CollectionViewControllerCell**

```
    @IBOutlet var videoWebView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet var singleDataImageView: UIImageView!

    var oneData:SingleData! {
        didSet{
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    func updateUI(){

        singleImageView.image = nil

        if (oneData.isVideo == true) {
            videoWebView.hidden = false
            singleDataImageView.hidden = true
            showVideo()
        } else {
            videoWebView.hidden = true
            singleDataImageView.hidden = false
            setImage(oneData.imageURL, singleDataImageView)
        }
    }

    func showVideo() {
        if let videoUrl = oneData.videoUrl {

            let replacedString = videoUrl.replace("watch?v=", withString: "embed/")
            videoWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
            videoWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
            videoWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

            let embededHTML = "<html><head><title>.</title><style>body,html,iframe{margin:0;padding:0;}</style></head><body><iframe width=\"\(videoWebView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(videoWebView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(replacedString)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"

            videoWebView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL:nil)

        }

    }


    func setImage(url : String?, _ imageView : UIImageView) {

        imageView.image = nil        
        imageUrlString = url


        if let cUrl = url {

            if let imageFromCache = imageCache.objectForKey(cUrl) as? UIImage {
                imageView.image = imageFromCache
                return
            }

            if let urlImage = NSURL(string: cUrl) {

                Request.sharedInstance.session.dataTaskWithURL(urlImage, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)

                        if self.imageUrlString == url {
                            imageView.image = imageToCache
                        }

                        imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: url!)
                    });

                }).resume()
            }
        }

    }
```

**SingleData**

```
class SingleData {

    var imageURL:String? = nil
    var videoUrl:String? = nil
    var isVideo:Bool? = false
    var dataAssets:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?    

    init(Data : Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?){
        dataAssets = Data
        if Data!["MediaContent"]!["MediaType"] as? Int == 2 {
            isVideo = true
        }

        imageURL = dataAssets!["MediaContent"]!["FileUrl"] as? String
        videoUrl = dataAssets!["MediaContent"]!["FileName"] as? String
    }

}
```

Comment: How much memory are you losing on each iteration? When you simulated memory warning, how much memory was recovered? Did you try temporarily removing web view altogether? Have you run this through instruments and identified what allocations are not getting released? (If you haven't seen it, refer to WWDC 2013 [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/410/) for practical demonstration of using Instruments to track down memory problems.)

Comment: @Rob each iteration I end up with 40-60mb more. Tried memory warning, but didn't see any difference. Going to try instruments tomorrow. Thanks for the info. :)

Comment: @Rob So the problem I think is that I have a collection view with nav bar and tapping on cell opens up a new collection view (nav bar still exists) I'm doing that via IB show (push) segue. I'm not sure but maybe this kind of presenting is wrong?